# DRF, Django Rest Framework. Render results as html

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I need to have a page with simple html which shows not pure JSON but formatted data with meta information.

I have this snipped of code.

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/list/<int:pk>', ProductViewSet.as_view({'put': 'update'}), name='product-view'),
    path('product/', ProductViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='product-view'),
]
```

I have this as result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETaGn.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
There are two main settings in Django related to the problem.
JSONRenderer allows to interpret json.
BrowsableAPIRenderer allows to format results as simple html.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
),
```

}